# Is it possible to digitally sign a VB6 application?

Tags: vb6, digital-signature

I wrote a VB6 application back in 2001 for a company and it's apparently still being used today.  The company is asking me to digitally sign it so that they can avoid the "Windows protected your PC" dialog:

[image]

Is it even possible to digitally sign a VB6 application?  If so, could someone point me to a tutorial or something like that.

Comment: You can sign any excutable and/or msi package (if you are using that for deployment). Search for "code signing" or "executable signing"; if you are using Installshield for example, then that can sign files already in build process.

Comment: StackOverflow really isn't for pointing people to tutorials. But yes, you should be able to sign an executable created by VB6 just like signing any other executable.

Comment: I digitally sign my apps using Inno Setup.  They can be signed manually but the Inno program has made it easy and automatic.  Search for the Inno tag and search in there for code signing.  There is a process involved in getting a certificate and it's not free, and it does not eliminate the warning dialog, it just shows you as the "Publisher" if the product was downloaded - looks more official.

Comment: @BillHileman What is the point of signing if it doesn't eliminate the warning dialog?

Comment: I wondered that myself.  It will still pop-up the dialog at least one time, except this time it will ask the user if they trust you as a publisher, and I'm fairly certain it validates the certificate as not expired and will not ask again for any other downloaded/installed apps from you unless your certificate expires.  Otherwise, it would ask the user every time from "unknown publisher"  That's about it, but I don't claim to be an expert.

Comment: @BillHileman That's the thing.  In the image I linked, it also only asks once and then never again, even though my exe is unsigned.

Comment: I think it's the fact that it's downloaded that triggers it.  If you merely run the downloaded setup a second time it definitely won't, but it could also be that the O/S is somehow also remembering this particular application from its previous install, I'm not sure.  I've noticed that if I e-mail my setup (back when .exe's and .zip's weren't blocked by most ISP's) the dialog did not appear - only if the customer downloaded it from my web site.

Comment: @BillHileman In my situation, it's not the setup that triggers the dialog - it's running the application for the first time.  And then the dialog never shows up again.

Comment: In some environments there is no actual difference between running signed and unsigned applications (warning color can be different). In some environments unsigned apps can be just blocked.

Comment: Microsoft collects executable signatures for their [SmartScreen reputation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139347/smart-screen-filter-still-complains-despite-i-signed-the-executable-why). Code-sign your executable, run it a couple of times and in about a day or two SmartScreen warning will go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off the general answer is "yes" - VB6 created EXE and DLL files can be digitally signed.

My understanding is that the signature process ultimately adds some "metadata" to the signed binary file which can be inspected later. This appears to be a general purpose Windows feature and not specific to VB6 or any other particular compiler (as far as I know).

The specific method I use to sign is a build step in [Visual Build Pro](https://www.kinook.com/VisBuildPro/). This signs the binary using a PFX certificate file and also timestamps it. (There are [other configuration options as well](https://www.kinook.com/VisBuildPro/Manual/index.htm?signcodeaction.htm)).

Note that I use this tool because it is also what we use for VB6 build automation (and it works well!) But I am confident other signing tools could be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

i think this would help you:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995332.aspx
>
> Summary: **CAPICOM** is a new security technology from Microsoft that
>   allows Microsoft **Visual Basic**, Visual Basic Script, ASP, and C++
>   programmers to easily **incorporate digital signing and encryption** into
>   their application. (5 printed pages)

Answer (score 1):

We were using `signtool.exe` from Platform SDK until it stopped producing sha-1 signatures (for XP compatibility) so had to migrate to [`osslsigncode`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/osslsigncode/) open-source implementation (w/ ugly cygwin dependency).

Here is our `codesign.bat` that we use to signs executables simultaneously with sha-1 and newer sha-256 signatures. Can sign .msi redistributables too.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set CYGWIN=nodosfilewarning
set tmpfile=%TEMP%\~$intermediate.tmp

:: set code-signing certficate .pfx file and password here
set osslsigncode="%~dp0osslsigncode.exe" sign -pkcs12 "%~dp0ucs_code_sign_current.pfx" -pass #########
set signtool="%~dp0signtool.exe" sign /f "%~dp0ucs_code_sign_current.pfx" /p ########

:: set default description and URL here (both options skipped if left empty)
set desc=
set durl=

:parse_params
if [%~1]==[] goto :parse_complete
if [%~1]==[/d] set desc="%~2"& shift /1 & shift /1 & goto :parse_params
if [%~1]==[/du] set durl="%~2"& shift /1 & shift /1 & goto :parse_params
set infile=%~1
set intype=%~x1
shift /1 & goto :parse_params
:parse_complete
if [%infile%]==[] goto :usage

if not [%desc%]==[] (
    set osslsigncode=%osslsigncode% -n %desc%
    set signtool=%signtool% /d %desc%
)
if not [%durl%]==[] (
    set osslsigncode=%osslsigncode% -i %durl%
    set signtool=%signtool% /du %durl%
)

if [%intype%]==[.msi] goto :msi_sign

%osslsigncode% -h sha1 -t http://timestamp.comodoca.com -in "%infile%" -out "%tmpfile%" > nul
if errorlevel 1 %osslsigncode% -h sha1 -t http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll -in "%infile%" -out "%tmpfile%" > nul
if errorlevel 1 exit /b 1
%osslsigncode% -nest -h sha2 -ts http://timestamp.comodoca.com -in "%tmpfile%" -out "%infile%" > nul
if errorlevel 1 %osslsigncode% -nest -h sha2 -ts http://timestamp.globalsign.com/?signature=sha2 -in "%tmpfile%" -out "%infile%" > nul
if errorlevel 1 exit /b 1
goto :cleanup

:msi_sign
::%signtool% /t "http://timestamp.comodoca.com" "%infile%"
::if errorlevel 1 %signtool% /t "http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll" "%infile%"
%osslsigncode% -h sha1 -t http://timestamp.comodoca.com -add-msi-dse -in "%infile%" -out "%tmpfile%" > nul
if errorlevel 1 %osslsigncode% -h sha1 -t http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll -add-msi-dse -in "%infile%" -out "%tmpfile%" > nul
if errorlevel 1 exit /b 1
copy "%tmpfile%" "%infile%" /y > nul

:cleanup
del "%tmpfile%" /q
goto :eof

:usage
echo usage: %~nx0 [options] ^<infile^>
echo.
echo where options:
echo     /d  ^<desc^>    Optional file description
echo     /du ^<url^>     Optional company URL
echo.
goto :eof
```

You'll need a commercial code-signing certificate in PFX format. You can tweak this batch to your needs or just use it as an inspiration for your impl.